# How to get array of arrays by grouping ids

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
let ar = [{
   asst: 1,
   v: 'b'
 }, {
   emp: 4
 }, {
   journal_id: 3
 }, {
   asst: 4
 }, {
   asst: 1,
   v: 'a'
 }, {
   asst: 1,
   v: 'c'
 }, {
   journal_id: 3
 }, {
   journal_id: 3
 }]
```

I want an array that has `asst` and `journal_id` as array of arrays and `emp` as just an object in the array that has array of `asst` and `journal_id`.
Like this:

`[[{asst:1, v: 'a'}, {asst:1, v: 'b'},{asst:1, v: 'c'}], [{asst:4}], [{journal_id:3}, {journal_id:3}, {journal_id:3}], {emp:4}]`

I have tried this:

```
let ar = [{
    asst: 1,
    v: 'b'
}, {
    emp: 4
}, {
    journal_id: 3
}, {
    asst: 4
}, {
    asst: 1,
    v: 'a'
}, {
    asst: 1,
    v: 'c'
}, {
    journal_id: 3
}, {
    journal_id: 3
}]
let asstArray = [],
    journalArray = [],
    fullArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    debugger
    if (ar[i].asst) {
        let contains = false;
        for (let j = 0; j < asstArray.length; j++) {
            for (let k = 0; k < asstArray[j].length; k++) {
                if (asstArray[j][k].asst == ar[i].asst) {
                    contains = true;
                    let d = asstArray[j][k];
                }
            }
            if (contains) {
                asstArray[j].push(ar[i]);
            }
        }
        if (!contains) {
            asstArray.push([ar[i]]);
        }
    } else if (ar[i].journal_id) {
        let contains = false;
        for (let j = 0; j < journalArray.length; j++) {
            for (let k = 0; k < journalArray[j].length; k++) {
                if (journalArray[j][k].journal_id == ar[i].journal_id) {
                    contains = true;
                }
            }
            if (contains) {
                journalArray[j].push(ar[i]);
            }
        }
        if (!contains) {
            journalArray.push([ar[i]]);
        }
    }
}
fullArray.push(asstArray);
fullArray.push(journalArray);
console.log(fullArray, "Full")
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/puoenwg6/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine the values of the wanted grouping keys to a single key and group by this value.

Objects without grouping keys are pushed to the result set directly.

```js
var array = [{ asst: 1, v: 'b' }, { emp: 4 }, { journal_id: 3 }, { asst: 4 }, { asst: 1, v: 'a' }, { asst: 1, v: 'c' }, { journal_id: 3 }, { journal_id: 3 }], keys = ['asst', 'journal_id'],
    keys = ['asst', 'journal_id'],
    result = array.reduce((hash => (r, o) => {
        if (keys.some(k => k in o)) {
            var key = keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
            if (!hash[key]) {
                r.push(hash[key] = []);
            }
            hash[key].push(o);
        } else {
            r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    })({}), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i don't want `emp` to be inside an array. i want it to be just an object

Comment: yould you have more than one object with `emp`?

Comment: yes i will have more than one `emp` and others like `emp` that aren't `asst` or `journal_id`

Comment: i dont want those that aren't `asst` or `journal_id` to be an array inside the array

Comment: do you need a special order as well?

Comment: no, i mean, you have the `emp` object at the end, maybe it is important to you?

Comment: is what i've done inefficient(assuming i fix it). because you've used stuff i cant understand and i dont know if old browsers support it

Comment: it works in all browers who understand `let`. it's plain ES6. your code soubel the inner look up for having the same keys in the result set and you could move for example the part of ` if (contains) {` inside where you set it to true and exit the inner loop by `continue` the outer loop. the `!contains` part works in this case without check (which is not necessary, too).

Comment: can you please explain the code. i now have `type_id` instead of using `asst` or `journal_id` keys to filter out. i now have an other situation where `{asst:1, v:'a', is_reverse:1 }, `{asst:1, v:'a', is_reverse:0 }` can have a `is_reverse` . i want a separate array for `asst` with `is_reverse==1` and separate for `is_reverse==0`. im trying to change the code but cant fully understand what you've done. https://jsfiddle.net/41z0r7bo/ . i dont understand the `join`

Comment: it would be easier, if you ask a new qurstion with govne data, what you tried and the wanted result. but anyway, in `keys` should be the keys of the array in which goruping should happen. if you have a different rule for checking `is_reverse`, you need this as well, either before or after checking the key, depending on the result.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a succint way to do it with `reduce` and `Object.values`. Also, the keys to check are declared in the initial value to the `reduce` function.

By using ES6 desctructuring, you can then rebuild the array you want at the end, with `emp`, out of the inner arrays.

With `emp` in the array:

```js
const ar = [
  { asst: 1, v: 'b' },
  { emp: 4 },
  { journal_id: 3 },
  { asst: 4 },
  { asst: 1, v: 'a' },
  { asst: 1, v: 'c' },
  { journal_id: 3 },
  { journal_id: 3 }
];

const result = Object.values(ar.reduce((accum, e) => {
  Object.keys(accum).forEach(k => {
    if (k in e) accum[k].push(e);
  });
  return accum;
}, { asst: [], journal_id: [], emp: [] }));

console.log(result);
```

With `emp` outside the inner array:

```js
const ar = [
  { asst: 1, v: 'b' },
  { emp: 4 },
  { journal_id: 3 },
  { asst: 4 },
  { asst: 1, v: 'a' },
  { asst: 1, v: 'c' },
  { journal_id: 3 },
  { journal_id: 3 }
];

let result = ar.reduce((accum, e) => {
  Object.keys(accum).forEach(k => {
    if (k in e) accum[k].push(e);
  });
  return accum;
}, { asst: [], journal_id: [], emp: [] });

const { emp, ...otherProps } = result;
result = [...Object.values(otherProps), emp[0]];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: i don't want emp to be inside an array. i want it to be just an object

Comment: Yes, updated, emp is now out: [
  [
    {
      "asst": 1,
      "v": "b"
    },
    {
      "asst": 4
    },
    {
      "asst": 1,
      "v": "a"
    },
    {
      "asst": 1,
      "v": "c"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "journal_id": 3
    },
    {
      "journal_id": 3
    },
    {
      "journal_id": 3
    }
  ],
  {
    "emp": 4
  }
]

Comment: thank you but i dont know how many objects i will have like `emp`. so it won't work. im sorry for un accepting your answer

Comment: Well, I can edit and put emp back in the array, the code will be even shorter, you now have both versions, and very short code

Comment: @Le guy, You should reedit your question then to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the array in a Map and then create a new array with the Map values:

```js
const data = [{"asst":1,"v":"b"},{"emp":4},{"journal_id":3},{"asst":4},{"asst":1,"v":"a"},{"asst":1,"v":"c"},{"journal_id":3},{"journal_id":3}];


const grouped = data.reduce(
  (result,item)=>{
    //key is item.asst or item.jornal_id or other
    const key = item.asst || item.journal_id || 'other';
    //set result(key) with empty array or existing array and conat new item
    return result.set(key,(result.get(key)||[]).concat(item));
  },new Map()
);
//get other values or empty array if they don't exist:
const others = grouped.get('other') || [];
//remove others if they exist:
grouped.delete('other');

//log array from Map values
console.log(others.concat([...grouped.values()]));
```

Comment: i don't want emp to be inside an array. i want it to be just an object

Comment: @Leguy Updated answer.